# How to constrain a variable depending on the value of an other variable in Gecode

Tags: constraint-programming, gecode

I am working with the [Gecode](http://www.gecode.org/index.html) toolkit and I want to model the following scenario.

I have two variables *x* and *y*. Depending on the value of *x*, *y* should be of a certain value. E.g. if *x* is 1, *y* should be 3, if *x* is 2, *y* should be 5. How should I model this in Gecode?

I currently use [reified constraints](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/MPG.pdf#subsection.4.3.3) to model this situation as can be seen in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/dvberkel/11319765). The crux is to use a *BoolVar* and two reified constraints to set the corresponding values.

```
for (IntVarValues i(x); i(); ++i) {
    BoolVar b = BoolVar(*this, 0, 1);
    rel(*this, x, IRT_EQ, i.val(), b);
    rel(*this, y, IRT_EQ, f(i.val), b);
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to model this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional transformation from x to y (i.e., one where each value for x is assigned a single value for y) is best done through the [element constraint](http://www.gecode.org/doc-latest/reference/group__TaskModelIntElement.html) when possible. The constraint takes an array that maps the domain of x to the domain of y, starting at the zero index.

For your example, you can use the following (assuming that `invalid` is an int not in the domain of `y` ):

```
IntArgs mapping(3,  invalid, 3, 5);
element(*this, mapping, x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to used the boolean expressions (e.g. MPG section 7.1.2 "Boolean expressions and relations") using the implication ("if else") construct with `>>`. Here are the examples you mentioned.

```
// if x == 1 then y == 3
rel(*this, (x == 1) >> (y == 3)); 
// if x == 2 then y == 5
rel(*this, (x == 2) >> (y == 5));
```

Note that Gecode also supports equivalence (using `==` instead if `>>`) for getting this relation both ways.

Comment: Note that using the boolean expressions is just another syntax for constructing reified expressions.